Unexplained changes in flutter source code, preventing the application from running
Note: While writing this question, I found the solution to it, but this has given rise to more questions, so for context don't skip the original question.
Original question:
I am getting this error when trying to run my flutter application:
../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart(2475,38): error
GC2F972A8: The argument type 'Size?' can't be assigned to the
parameter type 'Size' because 'Size?' is nullable and 'Size' isn't.

I run the app but all I get is this error and the app exits with Error: Build process failed.
I have no idea what's causing this as I tried reverting any recent changes I hade made to my code before the error appeared, but to no avail. The error message provides no reference to which one of my files is triggering the error.
This leads me to think there might be a problem with how Flutter is installed/configured in my computer. As a side note, all the flutter source code in flutter/dev, flutter/examples and flutter/packages is full of errors. Like over 400K errors in total. Most of them (if not all) are Undefined name or Target of URI doesn't exist errors.
On line 2475 of box.dart, the line mentioned in the above error message, I see the following:

From here, I go on to accidentaly solve the error as decribed below
My solution:
This suggests that somehow this null check has been removed, which is causing the error. I tried adding back the null check but it was removed every time I tried to save the file, because I was getting an unnecessary null check error:

It was only after I added // ignore: unnecessary_null_checks that I could add the null check and save the file. After this the orignal error dissapeared and I could run my application again.
This begs the question:

How was this null check even removed in the first place?
Why was dart code fixes preventing me from adding it back?
Why is the flutter source code full of errors and how does it still run?


what does flutter --version show? also, does flutter doctor -v say anything interesting?

Version: Flutter 3.22.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git Framework • revision 761747bfc5 (3 months ago) • 2024-06-05 22:15:13 +0200 Engine • revision edd8546116 Tools • Dart 3.4.3 • DevTools 2.34.3

Doctor:
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)     • Android SDK at C:\Users\hooph\AppData\Local\Android\sdk     X cmdline-tools component is missing       Run path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.     X Android license status unknown.       Runflutter doctor --android-licenses to accept the SDK licenses.       See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
Everything else is okay

and now, if you use  your flutter 3.22.2 and create a brand new project with flutter create foo what errors do you see in foo project?

The same: [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\hooph\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
X cmdline-tools component is missing
Run path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"
See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
X Android license status unknown.
Run flutter doctor --android-licenses to accept the SDK licenses.
See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.

what errors do you have in foo project (i am not asking about flutter doctor now)? what does flutter analyze show if you run it in the root of foo project?

No issues found

if no issues found, does it run as expected?

Yes, everything is fine

I was creating a flutter app, that stopped running, because there was an error in the flutter source code in flutter/packages/lib/src/rendering/box.dart. So my app was error free, but flutter source code had errors

in that application what do you have in pubspec.yaml in environment: sdk: '>=n.n.n <m.m.m' section? compare it with pubspec.yaml in  running foo project and try the  same numbers

environment:
sdk: '>=3.4.3 <4.0.0'

in both applications?

yes, both are the same

tried flutter clean in the root of your application and restarting ide?

I get this error with flutter clean: Flutter failed to delete a directory at "build". The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory. Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.

remove build folder by hand then and run flutter clean again

Did that, then tried to run the application and got a bunch of errors like firebase_firestore.lib(7ba01613985f32fe50e0c125a0414f54_firebase_firestore.dir_Debug_document_snapshot.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB '' was not found with 'firebase_firestore.lib(7ba01613985f32fe50e0c125a0414f54_firebase_firestore.dir_Debug_document_snapshot.obj)' or at ''; linking object as if no debug info  and .C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(166,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1. .

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
